# sqldeveloper query other users

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a database that has say 100 other_users.
I am logged in as the database owner and I want to query a specific table in all the other users schemas.

So let's say each schema has a table called propertyvalue.
I want to find out which schemas have this value set to TRUE.

Is there a way I can run a select statement against all the other users schemas without specifically pointing to an individual schema.

Something like:
select * from otherusers.propertyvalue where value = 'TRUE', which doesn't work as I have tried that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a statement that will write select statements to do this

```
SELECT 'SELECT '||owner||'.'||table_name||'.'||column_name ||
' FROM '||owner||'.'||table_name||';'
FROM All_Tab_Cols atc
WHERE atc.column_name = 'PROPERTYVALUE';
```

Run this statement as a user with select privilege on the table and then run the selects that are the output.

However tables with multiple rows will return all rows.  Are you expecting that there is only one row in each table?

You could also write an anonymous block that will open a cursor with the same statement and output the results to a file/table/output.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I will give that a shot.